# Beamer automatic ordering of overlays

Tags: beamer, overlays

I would like to order **automatically** some `alert`s (or other things) in some `uncoverenv`'s. `uncoverenv`'s should be continuously added but `alert`s should be just on the numbered slide. 
A minimal example is below. How to get the same result without manual numbering?

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Frame}
First

\alert<2>{A1}

\alert<3>{A2}

\begin{uncoverenv}<4->
Second

\alert<5>{A3}

\alert<6>{A4}
\end{uncoverenv}

\begin{uncoverenv}<7->
 Third

\alert<8>{A5}

\alert<9>{A6}
\end{uncoverenv}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! What do you mean with order automatically? Something like the `+` overlay specification (instead of the number)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Frame}
First

\alert<+(1)>{A1}

\alert<+(1)>{A2}

\begin{uncoverenv}<+(1)->
Second

\alert<+(1)>{A3}

\alert<+(1)>{A4}
\end{uncoverenv}

\begin{uncoverenv}<+(1)->
 Third

\alert<+(1)>{A5}

\alert<+(1)>{A6}
\end{uncoverenv}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you need the `(1)`? I always thought `+` would suffice.

Comment: @TeXnician That's what I tried first :)

Comment: I also tried this for nested overlays. But I could not make it.  For example `\uncover<+(1)>{U1\alert<+(1)>{U1}}` did not worked. Any suggestion?

Comment: @mert Should the same text be uncovered and alerted?

Comment: No. It is just for an example. The point: first uncover complete sentence on a slide and alert part of the sentence on another slide. The overlays should be only on those two slides. The text should become normal after that.

Comment: @mert try `\uncover<+(1)->{complete \alert<+(1)>{long} sentence}`

Comment: Thank you. But i'm sorry that i could not clairfy that i would like. It is like this: (overlay 1): a blue sentence "I'm here"  (overlay 2): "I'm `\alert`(here)". And then go on with normal text.